# Trabajar con json

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo una duda simple y rápida, estoy implementando un conversor de divisas no se si seria mejor cinco json(cada uno con los valores de la conversión un array que englobe a esos cinco json? 
Dudo si hay una manera que sea mas correcta y/o eficiente que la otra.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

creo que seria mejor con arrays, ya que de ahi extraerias el tipo de la divisa, tengo esto espoero te sirva

```html
//transaction types
var types = [
    {
        id : 'BD',
        description : 'Buy Dollars',
        labels : {
            from : 'Pesos',
            to : 'Dollars'
        },
        exchangeRate : 18.75,
        operation : 'divide'
    },
    {
        id : 'SD',
        description : 'Sell Dollars',
        labels : {
            from : 'Dollars',
            to : 'Pesos'
        },
        exchangeRate : 18.25,
        operation : 'multiply'
    }
];
//global variables
var selectedType;

function init() {
    console.log('Initializing page...');
    //add options to transaction type
    types.forEach(type => {
        //create option
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        //assign value and text
        option.value = type.id;
        option.text = type.description;
        //add option (child) to select (parent)
        document.getElementById('seltype').appendChild(option);
    });
    selectTransaction(types[0].id); //initialize transaction
    hideErrorLabel();//hide error label
}
function selectTransaction(typeId) {
    console.log('Select transaction...');
    clearValues();
    //find type
    types.forEach(type => {
        if (typeId == type.id) {
            //selected type
            selectedType = type;
            //labels
            document.getElementById('labelfrom').innerHTML = type.labels.from;
            document.getElementById('labelto').innerHTML = type.labels.to;
            //exchange rate
            document.getElementById('inputexchangerate').value = type.exchangeRate;
        }
    });
}
function convert() {
    console.log('Convert...');
    //get value from
    var ammountFrom = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inputfrom').value);
    if (!Number.isNaN(ammountFrom)) {
        var total = 0;
        if (selectedType.operation == 'multiply')
            total = ammountFrom * selectedType.exchangeRate;
        if (selectedType.operation == 'divide')
            total = ammountFrom / selectedType.exchangeRate;
        //display
        document.getElementById('inputto').value = formatCurrency(total);
    }
    else
        showErrorLabel('Invalid value for ' + selectedType.labels.from);
}
function clearValues() {
    console.log('Clear...');
    document.getElementById('inputfrom').value = '';
    document.getElementById('inputto').value = '';
    hideErrorLabel();
}
function hideErrorLabel() {
    document.getElementById('errorlabel').style.display = 'none';
}
function showErrorLabel(message) {
    document.getElementById('errorlabel').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('errorlabel').innerHTML = message;
}

function formatCurrency(ammount) {
    return '$ ' + ammount.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```